# replace text after match

Tags: sed, grep, awk

```
aaaaaaaaa   
bbbbbbbbb   
-th ccccccccc_RD \  

DDDDDDDD  
FFFFFFFF  
-th GGGGGGG_RD \
```

using sed/grep/awk etc, In the above text, if a line ends with "RD \" , replace "-th"  with "-to" at the beginning of line. Desired output:

```
aaaaaaaaa   
bbbbbbbbb   
-to ccccccccc_RD \  

DDDDDDDD  
FFFFFFFF  
-to GGGGGGG_RD \
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sed '/RD \\$/s/^-th/-to/'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/^-th\(.*RD \\\)/-to\1/' foo.txt
```

This is slightly complex because `\` is a special character and needs to be [escaped](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#ESCP). Since escaping is done by `\` itself, the way of matching a literal `\` is `\\`. The `\(` and `\)` are there to capture the matched pattern which is then referred to as `\1` in the substitution.

The syntax is easier in Perl since the parentheses do not need to be escaped:

```
perl -pne 's/^-th(.*RD \\)/-to$1/' foo.txt
```

In awk you would do:

```
awk '/RD \\$/{$1="-to"}{print}' foo.txt
```

Comment: didn't work:( it doent do anything, doesnt change anything

Comment: @RanaKhan do you have trailing spaces after the `\ ` at the end of the lines? Also, these solutions will not change the original file, you will need to redirect the output (`sed 's/^-th\(.*RD\\\)/-to\1/' foo.txt > bar.txt`) or use the `-i` flag with perl or sed: `sed -i 's/^-th\(.*RD\\\)/-to\1/' foo.txt`

Comment: @terdon Actually, I think it's because there's a space between `RD` and '\' (so your `awk` solution should work).

Comment: @JosephR. thanks, I had actually corrected that in the version I tested and forgot to update my answer :).

Comment: @RanaKhan see edited answer.

Comment: @JosephR.@terdon:  awk solution works just fine. thanks a lot.

Comment: @RanaKhan ...and the updated `sed` and `perl` ones don't? Also, please don't forget to mark a satisfactory answer as accepted! Upvoting and accepting is the way to say thanks on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RanaKhan if the updated `sed` and `perl` solutions don't work, you probably have whitespace after the last `\ `.

Comment: @terdon Actually, it's the other way around: trailing whitespace would trip the `awk` solution but not the `sed` or `perl` ones because you didn't anchor your pattern from the right.

Comment: @JosephR. oh, so I didn't, huh could have sworn I had. I had a `$` in there at some point but maybe only when testing.

Comment: @JosephR.@terdon when i pipe awk solution to another file and then trying to repeat the command for another match for example if line ends with  "SD \" , replace -th with -to. it does that job however it revert back the previous " RD \" change. Dont know if i am missing anything. Can i do like if " line ends with RD \ or SD \ , replace -th with -to?

Comment: @RanaKhan please post another question with followup issues. It is hard to understand what you mean from the comments.

Comment: @RanaKhan Or just modify the `awk` solution to `awk '(R|S)D \\$/{...`